# Hosted VPN Server

Tags: vpn, cloud-hosting

I would like to find a way to allow multiple computers to securely join a shared network. Ideally we would like to find a complete hosted solution, or run a server on Rackspace or Amazon EC2. I have attempted to install Openswan and xl2tpd on a server. It appears that I need to have an internal network that I can assign IP address from though. I don't have any cloud services that I need the clients to connect to, they only need to communicate with each other. In addition we will need to support Linux, iPhone, and Android clients. Does anyone have suggestions of hosting solutions, or on-line guides that would accomplish something similar to this?

As an added bonus it would be nice to have DNS resolution work between the connected clients.

Answer (score 0):

Aron,

Clarificaiton. When you say internal network are you thinking publicly routable IP addresses? If yes then you can you the IP address space defined in RFC 1918 to assign to the connected clients. Using private IPs they will be able to communicate with each other because the data will get encapsulated and then encrypted before being tunnelled to server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Disclaimer: I do not know of any hosted VPN service. I am trying to solve the problem you encountered while running your own service.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think that this is were I am getting a little confused. We don't have an internal network at all. In fact there is only a single NIC, the static WAN IP address. When configuring the VPN can I choose any of the RFC 1918 addresses even though I don't have a NIC on the server that has an IP within that subnet?

Comment: Aron, on linux you can always add a virtual interface . Something as simple as ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 would do that. Here is a link that will help you further. http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch03_:_Linux_Networking