# Hosted VPN Server

Tags: cloud, vpn

I would like to find a way to allow multiple computers to securely join a shared network. Ideally we would like to find a complete hosted solution, or run a server on Rackspace or Amazon EC2. I have attempted to install Openswan and xl2tpd on a server. It appears that I need to have an internal network that I can assign IP address from though. I don't have any cloud services that I need the clients to connect to, they only need to communicate with each other. In addition we will need to support Linux, iPhone, and Android clients. Does anyone have suggestions of hosting solutions, or on-line guides that would accomplish something similar to this?

As an added bonus it would be nice to have DNS resolution work between the connected clients.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosted VPN Server](http://serverfault.com/questions/209330/hosted-vpn-server)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/)

> LogMeIn Hamachi² is a hosted VPN service that securely connects devices and networks, extending LAN-like network connectivity to mobile users, distributed teams and business applications. You can easily create secure virtual networks on demand, across public and private networks.

Comment: I have tried LogMeIn Hamachi, but it doesn't seem to appear iPhone.